Odoo OWL error Service rpc is not available
I'm trying to use the Odoo OWL libraries and I'm following what is explained in the documentation.
import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";

export class ReviewUnderName extends Component {

    static template = "devolive_review.ReviewUnderName";
    static props = {};

    setup() {
        this.rpc = useService("rpc");
        this.loadData();
    }

    async loadData() {
        const response = await this.rpc(`/devolive/review/`);
        console.log("response", response);
    }

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error: Service rpc is not available
Does anyone know if there is extra steps to be able to use the rpc service with Odoo OWL Components?


In Odoo 18 source code i couldn't find any usage of useService("rpc").
The documentation is not always up-to-date (especially regarding JS stuff), so it might be an outdated feature (Odoo 15, 16, 17) ...
Instead i found this in Odoo 18:
import { rpc } from "@web/core/network/rpc";

As you can see here from Tests seems to be the new way of use the rpc:
Odoo 17 source code Web module
Odoo 18 Source Code Web module

Now, we have to report that the documentation is outdated... Thanks for the help.

@olive007 use the documentation as a "suggestion" ... always check in the code and compare old versions code with new one (like in this case).
Nice coding!
